# Cannot kill process rgmanager

Tags: linux, process, kill

I have

```
# ps aux | grep rgmana
root        4209  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D<   gen26   4:25 [rgmanager]
```

the

```
# kill -9 4209
```

has no effect. Only reboot solves the issue. Could you please explain this status `[rgmanager]` of the process?

Thank you!

EDIT 1: as suggested tried to investigate on the process

```
# strace -fp 4209
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Permission denied

# pstree 4209
rgmanager
```

Comment: this is not a question about how to kill generic process in D state but rather about rgmanager, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423521/process-perminantly-stuck-on-d-state) to know more about the state of the process. If reboot is a costly operation, try closing terminals from which the process was invoked.

Also you can use the following to learn what the process is doing:

```
strace -fp 4209
pstree 4209
```

Comment: thanks for links and commands, yes it happens quite rarely but when happens it is very annoying to do reboot entire machine, I've edit my post with your suggestions but no luck for now, will dig into `D state`!